# Allow failure for all tests if specific Error is thrown

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I have more than 2000 unittests/pytests in my project. Many of them ask API, but API can be lagged. Is there a way to expect `APILagError` in every single test and throw SKIP/XFAIL for any test if this error occurs?

Current:

- test_1: ok
- test_2: fail
- test_3: ok

result: 1 fail, 2 ok => tests failed

Wanted:

- test_1: ok
- test_2: skip/xfail
- test_3: ok

result: 2 ok, 1 skipped/xfailed => tests passed

Comment: Is your question about the pytest library or the unittest library?

Comment: Both as tests are run by both of them

Comment: Can you catch that exception in your test? In this case you can just skip the test (`raise unittest.SkipTest('message')` / `pytest.skip()`).

Comment: For unit tests, you can override `runTest` in a base class if you are able to derive your test classes from it, in pytest you may use a fixture, if that is possible.

Comment: Or you could write a decorator that wraps that excpetion handling and use it for the tests - though this would imply to touch each test.

Comment: All that said I very much recommend to go the way @Chris proposes in his answer.

Comment: @mrbean-bremen Hmm, this would need to decorate all tests at once. But I heard this can also be done somehow

Answer (score 3):

I feel your pain. I'm going to do that annoying SO thing where I don't actually answer your question as you posed it, but suggest you change directions. You should choose one of:

1. mock that API so it doesn't time out any more and your tests aren't flakey
2. treat your API lag as normal behavior and increase the allowed duration of API calls so typical lag time doesn't result in a failed test
3. treat your API lag as a bug and go fix it so your tests pass

#### Why are flakey tests bad?

Flakey tests mean you can't tell the difference between broken code and a slow API call. So your tests aren't helping you catch bugs. So what's the point?

#### Why would I ever mock the API? It's not "real"!

You'd do this if you want to test anything outside of the API. Decouple your logic from the API's behavior to eliminate flakiness and make your code more maintainable.

You might also be able to get a similarly-behaved but much faster API to test against as your mock. Like check out the API's code locally and populate it with a small set of data. Hit that in your tests instead of the production API. That would let you check its logic separate from its lagginess.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do all of these (except 3 as I am not the developer responsile for the API), but none helped so far, that's why I asked here.

Comment: Hmmm so either (1) trust the API developers to do their job and replace that API with simple mocks in your tests, or (2) use a different API that is reliable, or (3) if you must use it and you don't trust it and you can't fix it... gosh, that sucks, but I don't think testing will help. The decorator idea from MrBean Bremen that translates exceptions into `raise SkipTest()` might be your best bet just to silence the noise.

Comment: (1) works well for simple tasks, but not for the complicated ones :/ (2) there's no other API than the official one and (3) yeah, it sucks and yeah, the idea of decorating everything (with a hack to decorate everything without actually decorating everything) is the only solution I am aware of

Comment: I also try to negotiate with API maintainers, but this is for a long time :/